# Проблема при переключении между фрагментами. Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

Использую шаблон Navigation Drawer + Fragments. Страница "Главная" дублирует меню и по нажатию кнопки переключает фрагмент на нужный мне. Правда возникла одна проблема, после нажатия кнопки, открывается нужный мне фрагмент, но заголовок AppBar остаётся с название "Главная" + выбранный пункт в меню так же остаётся "Главная".

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnrec, btning, btnset;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Установка темы без родного бара + фуллскрин
        setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Инициализация цвета иконок меню
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_main, R.id.nav_recept, R.id.nav_ingred, R.id.nav_setting)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);



    }

    public void onClick(View view) {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Главная

```
public class m_main_frag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private m_main_view mmainview;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mmainview = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(m_main_view.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_main, container, false);


        Button btnrec = root.findViewById(R.id.btnrec);
        btnrec.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button  btning = root.findViewById(R.id.btning);
        btning.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnset = root.findViewById(R.id.btnset);
        btnset.setOnClickListener(this);
        return root;
    }
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent;

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnrec:
                    Fragment m_recept_frag = new m_recept_frag();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction_recept = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction_recept.replace(R.id.main_activ, m_recept_frag);
                    transaction_recept.commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btning:
                    Fragment m_ingred_frag = new m_ingred_frag();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction_ingred = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction_ingred.replace(R.id.main_activ, m_ingred_frag);
                    transaction_ingred.commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnset:
                    Fragment m_setting_frag = new m_setting_frag();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction_setting = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction_setting.replace(R.id.main_activ, m_setting_frag);
                    transaction_setting.commit();
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Во фрагментах сделай так

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mainActivity.setTitle("Заголовок");
}
```